# draw polygon with hole using mouse on google maps

Tags: google-maps, drawing

I want to draw a polygon with holes using mouse on Google maps.

Google maps API provides way to draw polygon with holes using given co-ordinates, but how to draw using mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution myself. The solution is - first draw two polygons one inside another with mouse and then take co-ordinates of those two polygons, prepare required 'innerCoords' and 'outerCoords' array from those two polygons and pass it to Google Maps method

```
var myPolyWithHole = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: [outerCoords, innerCoords],
          strokeColor: '#FFC107',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FFC107',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
```

*Delete previously drawn two polygons